# How to implement Git quickly with existing files containing sequential versions of code

Tags: git, version-control

As my R code gets increasingly longer and harder to manage, I am trying to implement Git to improve my workflow.

I currently save sequential versions of the code with 'save as' and meaningful filenames, e.g. 'Mycode - ver 0.1.01', 'Mycode - ver 0.1.02', ...., 'Mycode - ver 0.1.25'. This is probably what many of us will do before using any Version Control System.

#### What I did:

I started the migration to Git by creating a repository, copied *all* 25 R-scripts into the folder before committing each one in turn, from earliest to the most recent.

#### The problem:

It hit me that I could be doing this wrongly: I think instead of having a folder with a single R-script with 25 revisions (which should be the correct way), I was really creating a folder of 25 separate files.

**Thus, my question: is there a way to get all 25 versions of my code into Git quickly and correctly?**

At this point, I can only think of creating an empty file, cutting-and-pasting the contents of all 25 files into it one at a time and committing each in turn. This is obviously time-consuming and error-prone.

Before starting, I went through the Git documentation (at least up to chp 3 on branching) and many online tutorials. While they introduce basic Git concepts, e.g. how Git takes a snapshot of the files in the repository with every commit, Git branching, merging, etc., I could not find resources on how to migrate when one is in the *middle* of a project like my situation.

If my understanding is incorrect in any way, I humbly request for any correction. Thanks in advance!

An aside: I am using SmartGit due to comments in SO that it's easy to learn, but I am open to any advice using Bash or any other GUI client.

Edit:

I am running Git on Windows XP.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: 3 hours of reading only to have me end up with a post in SO seeking help, yet within 15 minutes, there are already 3 proposed solutions! Amazing, and thanks! Now, I'll try all the solutions in turn ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else can help you with windows scripting, however if you have bash you can do something like that :

```
find -iname 'MyCode*' | sort | while read f; do
      cat "${f}" > MyCode.r; git add MyCode.r; git commit -a -m "$f";
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your question you are dealing with twenty-five versions of *one file*, so I will presume that is the case. I think the easiest way to get the revisions into git in such a simple case would be to shell-script it, based around a loop which looks something like

```
for x in `seq 1 25`; do
    cp "Mycode - ver 0.1.`printf '%02d' "$x"`" "Mycode"
    git add "Mycode"
    git commit -m "revision $x"
done
```

Of course the timestamps will all be absurdly close together. You can do some lower-level git-fiddling to fix that but it requires "history rewriting" so *do it before uploading to a public repo*.

*EDIT:* obviously with some slight syntax changes you could script the same thing very easily in Windows batch-file. If you stay in the same directory you don't have to worry about back-slash vs. forward-slash directory-separators, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for bash. It should work on any operating system, as long as you have `realpath` installed.

You just need a simple script. Hopefully, sorting the files in reverse order by last modified date (using `ls -tr`, as I have done here) or by name, should list them in the correct order. Something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
orig_dir="$(realpath $1)"
desired_repo_name="$2"
desired_filename="$3"
mkdir "$desired_repo_name"
cd "$desired_repo_name"
git init
for file in $(ls -tr $orig_dir/*); do
  cp "$file" "$desired_filename"
  git add "$desired_filename"
  git commit -m "Importing from $file"
done
```

Make the script executable (I am not sure if this is necessary on Cygwin on Windows):

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Run it:

```
./script.sh A B C
```

where A is the directory containing the original files, B is the desired repository folder (which the script will create), and C is the filename to use for all versions of your file.

This script does not date stamp the git revisions correctly - they will all be date stamped with the current date. However that functionality would be easy to add.